# How to Integrate 2checkout payment gateway with React.js

Tags: reactjs, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am looking for a code sample or well documentation for the integration of the 2checkout gateway in reactjs project. I was trying to use 2pay.js https://verifone.cloud/docs/2checkout/API-Integration/2Pay.js-payments-solution/2Pay.js-Payments-Solution-Integration-Guide/Basic-Implementation-for-2Pay.js-Payments-Solution but it does not work for me,

could you please help me to provide good well documentation or a code sample?

Thank you
Zelal